# Why is my recursive loop printing the last value twice at the end?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I am attempting to recursively loop through a number of files in a directory with subdirectories, looking for object attributes to match on.

However, it seems that when I actually perform a recursive loop, I cannot get the desired outcome and it seems I am printing my last debug log twice for some reason.

Can somebody enlighten me on what is going wrong?

```
 data = { myFile: { new: { name: 'new' } } }

  recursiveLoop(data, name) {
      let myArr = ['one'];
      console.log(1);
      for (const value of Object.values(data)) {
          console.log(2);
          if (value.name) {
              console.log(3);
              if (value.name === name) {
                  console.log(4);
                  myArr.push('value.name');
              }
          } else {
              console.log(5);
              recursiveLoop(value, name);
          }
      }
      console.log(6);
      return myArr;
  };

  x = recursiveLoop(data, 'new');
  console.log(x);
```

The debugging console log reads:

```
1
2
5
1
2
3
4
6
6
```

The array printed at the end is empty...

I cannot figure out what is going wrong :-(

My goal is to have an array: `['new']`

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/recursive-check) with it in

Answer (score 2):

There are two calls of `recursiveLoop`:

1. The "main" one: `recursiveLoop(data, 'new');`
2. The "recursive" one: `recursiveLoop(value, name);` (which is called only one time as you can see from your log output)

As there are two calls and there is only one way to return from the function, `console.log(6);` is called two times.

Comment: Solid deduction.

Comment: Sorry, it's my first time with proper recursion. My initial thought would be that when it hits the `else` block and calls back to itself it would then go through and hit the `if` block, when it reaches the return it would only complete that step once. Basically I expected the exact same debug log, but only one instance of `"6"`. But now I will know this for future! Thanks for the help :-)

Comment: I still can't get it to work however :-/ My goal is to have the `value.name` value being outputted in the array, but I cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Define `recursiveLoop(data, name, depth)` (you will need a third parameter), call it as

```
x = recursiveLoop(data, 'new', 0);
```

at first, then always increase it, by calling

```
recursiveLoop(value, name, depth + 1);
```

and you will always know whether it is the first call or not. Then change your line which runs twice to

```
if (!depth) console.log(6);
```

so it will run only at the very first time. Your other mistake is that you add `value.name` as a string to your array, not as a value, so change this line

```
myArr.push('value.name');
```

to

```
myArr.push(value.name);
```