# Why is my recursive loop printing the same value twice? - JAVA

Tags: java, recursion

The following code recursively reduces x by 1 until it is equal to y. It prints a string representing the recursion process.
I do not want the starting value of x to be printed in the string.

```
private static String createPath(int x, int y, String path) {
        if (x > y) {
            path += "(" + (x-1) + "," + y + ") ";
            return createPath(x - 1, y, path);
        }
        else 
            return path += "(" + x + "," + y + ") ";
    }
```

When I input something such as:

```
System.out.println(createPath(5, 1, ""));
```

I get the following output:

```
(4,1) (3,1) (2,1) (1,1) (1,1)
```

Why is the final value (1,1) being printed twice? I noticed that when I remove (x-1) from

```
path += "(" + (x-1) + "," + y + ") ";
```

The output becomes:

```
(5,1) (4,1) (3,1) (2,1) (1,1)
```

But once again, I do not want (5,1) to be printed in the string. Also, I have had a look at [Why is my recursive loop printing the last value twice at the end?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57029711/why-is-my-recursive-loop-printing-the-last-value-twice-at-the-end) but it did not seem to help me.

Comment: The removal of `-1` would seem like the correct solution to me. If you do not want the `(5,1)` to be printed though, why do you call `createPath` with `5` as initial `x`?

Comment: @Siguza There is no reason, it is simply just the starting value of `x` I have chosen. If I had chosen `4` for `x` it would make no difference to my statement **I do not want the starting value of x to be printed in the string**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition should be as follows:

```
private static String createPath(int x, int y, String path) {
    if (x <= y) {
        return path;
    }
    path += "(" + (x - 1) + "," + y + ") ";
    return createPath(x - 1, y, path);
}
```

This definition will ensure that as soon as `x <= y`, the value of `path` will be returned.

Comment: Thank you sir, you helped me understand what my problem was but it was not what you just explained haha. Instead of `return path += "(" + x + "," + y + ") ";` all I have to do is  `return path;`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply because when `x==2` and `y==1` condition `x>y` is true and `"(" + (x-1) + "," + y + ") "` returns (1,1)

Answer (score 1):

Correct solution:

```
    private static String createPath(int x, int y, String path) {
        if (x > (y + 1))
            return createPath(x - 1, y, path + "(" + (x - 1) + "," + y + ") ");
        else 
            return path + "(" + (x - 1) + "," + y + ") ";
    }
```

note, `if (x > (y + 1))` and `(x - 1)` in else branch.

the execution order of your function is the following:

```
createPath(5, 1) => createPath(4, 1, "(4,1)");
createPath(4, 1) => createPath(3, 1, "(3,1)");
createPath(3, 1) => createPath(2, 1, "(2,1)");
createPath(2, 1) => createPath(1, 1, "(1,1)");
// and the last one in the else branch
createPath(1, 1) => createPath(1, 1, "(1,1)");
```

as you can see you need to add (x - 1) in the else branch and modify your if statement in such way that you get to the else branch earlier to prevent it from going to below 1.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the reason why the final value was being printed twice was because the `else` return statement was adding the final value of (x,y) unnecessarily. For example,

```
else 
      return path += "(" + x + "," + y + ") ";
```

The above code is executed once `x` is no longer greater than `y` , meaning the value of path that was passed through `createPath(int x, int y, String path)` contains (x,y) which are equal to one another. However, what the else statement above does is once again add the values of `x` and `y` to `path`, when all that needs to be done is `return path;`.